# how to determine if the partition being deleted existed or not

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there a way to determine if the `delete` operation actually deleted a partition if the partition existed? I am running the following `cql` queries. I was hoping that I'll get an error when I'll specify an invalid partition but I don't

```
cqlsh:mypartition> select * from users;

 bucket | email         | authprovider | firstname | lastname | confirmed | hasher     | id                                   | password     | salt
--------+---------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+------
      1 | test@test.com |  credentials |        fn |       ln |     False | someHasher | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | somePassword |

(1 rows)
cqlsh:mypartition> DELETE FROM users WHERE bucket=1 AND email='test1@test.com';
cqlsh:mypartition> select * from users;

 bucket | email         | authprovider | firstname | lastname | confirmed | hasher     | id                                   | password     | salt
--------+---------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+------
      1 | test@test.com |  credentials |        fn |       ln |     False | someHasher | 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 | somePassword |

(1 rows)
cqlsh:mypartition> DELETE FROM users WHERE bucket=1 AND email='test@test.com';
cqlsh:codingjedi> select * from users;

 bucket | email | authprovider | firstname | lastname | confirmed | hasher | id | password | salt
--------+-------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+----+----------+------

(0 rows)
cqlsh:codingjedi>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Deletes are just writes, and Cassandra sorts it out in compaction.

Comment: Right. And note that this isn't some unfortunate missing feature, rather it is by design: This is how Cassandra achieved its fast write performance. Especially on low-IOPS spinning disks. In Cassandra, a write (and a delete, which is just writing a deletion - a.k.a. a "tombstone") just get written to memory and to sequential files - but do not need a read to check the previous value.